# TVS RP-45 roll paper printing

Tags: c#, sql, printing, crystal-reports

I have a receipt made using Crystal Reports where the page is 4 inch wide and the height should be dynamic. I set the height to 2 inches, because I don't know how to make it dynamic. The printer is a [TVS RP-45 Justbill printer](http://www.tvs-e.in/pos/home-just-bill-rp45.asp).

The printer is ejecting paper after printing. How do I stop this from happening?

Any solution besides Crystal Reports would be helpful. The program is written in C# .NET 2.0 Winforms and connects to a SQL Server 2005 database.

```
Report Header Section
                      Bill no : 101
______________________________________________
Detail Section
Item Code               Qty           Amount
[ItemCode]             [Qty]         [Amount]
______________________________________________
Report Footer Section
Grand Total                      [GrandTotal]
______________________________________________
```

The **Report Footer Section** is using around 2 inches so I set the Height of the paper to 2 inches. This did not solve the problem. The paper height is now 2 times what it should be if there is more than 1 item.

The printer uses roll paper and it should feed more paper proportionally with the number of items sold.

Please help me solve this without wasting paper.

Comment: Try checking the printer settings.  Roll feed printers often have settings for form feeding after jobs.

Comment: I already check that, no advantage.
I have choose tractor feed from printer properties.

Comment: And there are no page feeds on the document you are printing?  Any overlap horizontally or vertically in the print size will cause feeding.  Possibly including any unprintable areas, the page size may need to fit within the printable area of the printer.

Comment: I have no answer, just suggesting things to check.

Comment: I have checked all the settings.Thanks

Comment: @Sourav I know that your using C#, but there was a solution here [How to Stop the Printer after last line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563884/how-stop-the-printer-after-print-the-last-line-in-the-crystal-report-vs2005/12582095#12582095) I know it's not the most elegant but it's something to look at

Comment: What version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Comment: When you print preview, do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Try setting the footer to 0" and add a CAN GROW option to it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to suggest something a little different.

Create a new document in Notepad on Windows or a plain text editor on other OS's.

This document (.txt) should just contain one line: TEST_LINE_1

1. Send that document to your printer and see if the same after print feed continues.
2. If it continues to feed after the single line of print:
   Check settings as follows ( I know you said you've already checked ):

From the manual:
[ http://www.tvs-e.in/pos/pdf/RP-45%20User%20Manual.pdf ]
To set the factory settings of the printer, first press FONT, Line feed and 
PRINT buttons  together  and  then  switch ON  the  printer  using ON/OFF 
switch.

- Usually you have to hold those buttons while switching it off and back on - hold until the printer prints its config off.

If you can post back with what the print out says word for word that would be good.

1. If it doesn't feed after the single line:
   Your design is most likely too wide for the format/internal limits of the paper width and it's wrapping around onto a new line for every line you have.

Are you able to post a photo of what is being printed with how much paper it's on-feeding by?

1. Try printer on a different computer or laptop if possible with single line text file (as above) or with your custom report job - is it the same output?
2. If the printer is installed as a USB device: Remove all traces of the driver files and completely uninstall it as a printer - reinstall fresh copies and see what happens - the same?

I appreciate some of these things always 'seem obvious' when you're up against a problem but it does help to start over with the most basic of things..

Answer (score -1):

Just remove headers and footers, It will work fine.

Comment: While this may solve the questioners problem, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.about how to phrase answers and edit accordingly.