# how stop the printer after print the Last line in the crystal report (VS2005)

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, report

i have a crystal report in vs2005. I have to print this report in rollpaper with dotmatrix printer.
After printng the report it omit some waste spaces.

I have to stop the printer where the last line was printed.

i was seached with this problem but i am unable to find a solution.

please helpme to come out this problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved this Problem, wecan't print dircetly in rollpaper with Crystal Reports for dynamic length(ie Dynamic Page Size), Because in Crystal report we have a standard page size(A4,Letter,Envelope etc ..)

For this Case Please Go through this Article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322090. This Article describes how print a raw data.

Write and allign all your data in a Textfile and Print.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the report itself make sure that any footers are suppressed, this may be causing the paper waste.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In Report footer i have some data, But i have no data in page footer and the Checkbox(Suppress) is checked.

Comment: you can try adding "not onlastrecord" to your report footer and/or page footer and see how that works.  I haven't worked with rollpaper or dotmatrix in quite awhile so I'm not sure how crystal will react with

Comment: if we give "not onlastrecord" also leave the paper because it print through the the page setup(A4,Letter,Legal). But i solve this problem, i write the crystal report data in to text file, after i send it to printer as RAW. It's working fine. Thanks for your Valuable guidelines.